# How can I randomise <li> elements on page refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, random, shuffle

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could go about randomising an list each time the page is refreshed?

A jQuery solution would be perfect as I'm already using it.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a look at [this Shuffle plugin](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-shuffle-plugin/)

```
$('ul').shuffle();
```

Comment: @cordial you're welcome. if it works out fine for you don't forget to accept the answer (checkmark near the score). And welcome on SO!